# Google Maps V3 Authentication & Duplication Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to implement google maps onto our website.

The website baiscally has a page with sections on the page that can load dynamically via jquery.load().

In one of these sections another page loads via the jQuery.Load() function  which fills the content for a popup window (a div with fancy styling)

Now in the div i am making use of the JqueryUI tab control and one of the tabs contain the google maps map.

Please see my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript"
            src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=xxxxxxxxxx..&sensor=false&v=3&callback=initialize">
</script>

 <script>
        document.domain = '<?php echo $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"]; ?>';

        $(function() {
            $("#tabs").tabs();
        });

        function initialize() {
            var mapOptions = {
                zoom: 8,
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644)
            };

            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
                    mapOptions);
        }

        function loadScript() {
            var script = document.createElement('script');
            script.type = 'text/javascript';
            script.src = 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=..........&sensor=false&v=3&callback=initialize';
            document.body.appendChild(script);
        }

        window.onload = loadScript;

    </script>
```

The map loads successfully but I get the following errors:
 1. Warning: you have included the Google Maps API multiple times on this page. This may cause unexpected errors.
 2. Exceeding connection limit - which is impossible

Any help?

Comment: You have a `script` tag at the top which loads the maps API, and also, an onload function that creates a duplicate `script` tag for the same file. So that's why you're getting the 'multiple times' error.

Comment: *Why* are you including the Google script more than once? There's no need to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove first script tag.
i.e.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/jskey=xxxxxxxxxx..&sensor=false&v=3&callback=initialize">
```

Because "loadScript()" is already loading google map api.